# How to execute multiple commands through perl script

Tags: perl, command-line

I am trying to use perl to run two different commands - both of which need to be executed in a separate command prompt.

Here are some of the details:

when I run

```
system('start cmd /k "cd c:\PerlExamples && perl Perl_Ex_1.pl"');
```

it works as expected - it opens a new command prompt, paths to the directory I need and runs my script.

However, I want to use this system... command in a loop where each time I am running a different example script.
But when I run the following lines of code,

```
my $cmd = "perl Perl_Ex_1.pl";
system("start cmd /k cd c:\PerlExamples && $cmd");
```

it opens a new command prompt and paths to the directory I need. But it runs my example script in the original window and not in the newly opened command prompt.

Is there a way for me to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `/c` instead of `/k`? I cannot test right now (no Windows available). Or try without `start`.

Comment: The issue is that I need to keep that window open and not close it.

Comment: Could it be because you don't have quotes around ` cd c:\PerlExamples && $cmd` in the second command?

Comment: @user2243865 If I put quotes around that, it considers $cmd as part of string instead of as a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the wisdom of the perl monks, I found the solution to my problem.

Link to the solution:
http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1173278

The solution is to either use:

```
my $cmd = "perl Perl_Ex_1.pl";
system(qq{start cmd /k "cd c:\\PerlExamples && $cmd"});
```

or use:

```
my $cmd = "perl Perl_Ex_1.pl";
system qq[ start /D c:\\PerlExamples cmd /k  $cmd ];
```

Thank you.